# Why does AWS Lambda not upload images to S3 properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm having an issue with .NET Core 2.0 framework regarding the uploading of image files to S3 using the AWS SDK.

When I POST to my endpoint running on a local IIES it works perfectly and I can see the generated file in S3 without any issues.

The problem is the following:
After a serverless deploy to AWS Lambda, the same .NET Core endpoint that produced a perfect result in my local environment behaves way differently when it's running on a lambda.

I have reasons to suspect this is not a problem with roles, policies or any other permissions related issue.

Why? Well, in the first place, the Lambda does upload the file to S3, it can read, list and put objects inside the bucket without any problems at all.

"Then what's the problem?" You might be wondering.
The problem is that the uploaded picture becomes almost twice as big as the original and the **BYTES** and **content** are completely changed after submission. Even the magic number bytes change, I mean the ones at the beginning of the file representing the file type.

This is the result:
[image: Files I uploaded]

The first one is the one I uploaded locally, and the second one is the Lambda uploaded picture. And yes, they're the same picture.

Localhost:
[image]

Lambda:
[image]
In case it helps at all, here's the C# code implementing the S3 SDK:

```cs
try
        {
            var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(s3Config.Region);
            _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(region);

            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    InputStream = memoryStream,
                    Key = fileName,
                    BucketName = s3Config.BucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl,
                    ContentType = image.ContentType
                };
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
                var link = "http://{0}.s3-{1}.amazonaws.com".FormatWith(s3Config.BucketName, s3Config.Region);
                return ResponseMessages.DocumentUploaded(fileName, link);
            }
        }
```

Where "image" is an IFormFile variable.
If there's any other information I can provide in order to debug this please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I have had a lot of problems with uploading images through AWS APIGateway. I would spend time looking at that. How is the file getting posted to the endpoint? Through multipart/formdata, as base64 in the json?

Comment: It's being posted as part of a form-data, IFormFile Image { get; set; }

Comment: A change in bytes and filesize is usually a symptom of an encoding problem. Do the two objects have the correct `content-type` and `content-encoding` on s3?

Comment: @FranRoura i will suggest please check your Lambda Role settings. It will work from your development machine because you are using SDK to upload image to S3. But in Lambda case your it requires S3 full permissions separately. The associated role should have full permission to S3 bucket. Code seems OK to me it should be working there. Please use cloud watch to write down traces in your Lambda to find whats going on if there is permission issue you can see that in traces/logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry I missed this question, but long story short is that you need to tell API Gateway that you are going to provide binary data as your payload.

Here's an illustrative example:
[image]

The only thing you then have to do is convert the payload in binary to base64 when uploading to S3 only (which is not a problem, because your application received it in binary, thus saving [33%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) on the payload size).

I have created a NodeJS example, so you'd just need to modify it accordingly to C#:

```
const upload = body => {
    const id = uuid();
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: BUCKET,
            Key: id + '.jpg',
            Body: new Buffer(body.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64'),
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return rej(err);
            }
            return res({
                bucket: BUCKET,
                key: id + '.jpg'
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I may be a bit late to the party, but hopefully this makes you understand what the problem was.

Comment: Two years later and I still come back to this answer whenever I have the encoding issue and forgot it was because of the API Gateway settings. Sorry for not marking it as the right answer before, I fixed that now :)

Comment: haha. I am glad it still helps you! Thanks for marking it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using SES and SNS to debug the lambda in real-time.
I literally had to serialize the IFormFile object as a string and email it to myself on each image upload. I also set up an SMS with the length of the IFormFile.

Just in case this helps anyone else in the future; the extra bytes were already there as soon as the request was processed. I mean, the 29.7KiB file was outputting 53000~ bytes as it's `.Length` in the first instant of the endpoint's execution, so it was not a Lambda problem (Might have been our API Gateway's or .NET Core's config though).

Anyways, we fixed it by expecting a base64 string as an `application/json` property and decoding it like this:

```cs
var imageParts = base64Image.Split(',').ToList();
var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(imageParts[1]);
await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    InputStream = memoryStream,
    Key = fileName,
    BucketName = s3Config.BucketName,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl,
    ContentType = "image/{0}".FormatWith(fileExtension)
};
await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
```

Where base64Image is a base64 encoded string.

In case anyone ends up in the same place we were yesterday, just ignore the actual root cause of the problem and use Base64, it might not be as performant as a file inside a FormBody, but sure you'll save some time.